# Visual Studio Icon on bottom of web page in Dev mode - Why? And how to make it go away?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm running Visual Studio 16.9.3  This morning when doing web development, I noticed an odd change.  On one of my web pages when running in debug mode, there was a Visual Studio icon in the lower left corner of the page that I have never seen before.  See below:

[image]

Clicking the icon opens this context menu:
[image]

If I select the "Enable Inspector" menu choice then in the lower right corner of the Visual Studio window this is displayed:

[image]

However nothing else happens and that message never goes away.

What is this feature? What is it suppose to do? And how can I make it go away an not display and icon on my web page while doing development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That menu is from the [Web Live Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WebToolsTeam.WebLivePreview) extension, which is currently in preview. You can read a little more about it [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/introducing-web-live-preview/) or see a video with more recent details [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qfy467I6Yts&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oX-DBuRG4u58ZTAJgBAeQ-t&index=13).

I'm not sure how it suddenly became enabled for you in 16.9 (that should only happen if you install the extension from the marketplace), but you can disable it by clicking on Close from the menu and choosing the option appropriate for you.

That said, we'd also appreciate if you used the various feedback mechanisms mentioned in the links above or in VS itself to let us know some more details of your setup so we could get to the bottom of why it is stuck on `Generating Logical Tree...` for you. We'd rather it be useful so you don't want to turn it off!

Comment: I appreciate that Microsoft monitors for questions related to their products.  Well done.  Basee on the article you linked to I suspect my stuck Generating Logical Tree... is due to my project being a .NET Core MVC Web Application and it looks like the tool doesn't yet support that. Once it supports my environment it looks like it might be a handy tool, I'd certainly take it for a spin.

Comment: I just wasted 6 hours because if Web Live Preview extension.  Ug.  I work on a _big_ site with 300k+ lines of code.  Suddenly the tab key quit working on the site in my dev environment for tabbing between fields on a website form.  Unacceptable of course. So I proceed to hunt down the bug that I had apparently introduced.  I checked my global event handles, nothing, I check page level handlers, nothing. I created a form without many js libraries, nothing, I created a bare html form, still no tab support. I reset chrome and on an on. The fixed? Disabling Web live preview! Ug.  6hrs lost.

Comment: Ugh. I'm sorry about that! We found the bug in the 0.5 release that caused the dialog component we use to eat the tab key even if it wasn't visible. We fixed it in the 0.6 release that is rolling out today. I'm sorry we didn't get that fixed sooner to keep you from wasting that time!

Comment: No worries.  Goes with being a developer.  I posted my experience not to vent but to indicate the issue and severity. Glad you found the bug.  Will save untold number of dev hours hunting for bugs in their own web code, that aren't there.